# How do I make use of multipliers to generate a simple adder?

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, quartus-ii, synthesis, system-verilog

I'm trying to synthesize an Altera circuit using as few logic elements as possible. Also, embedded multipliers do not count against logic elements, so I should be using them. So far the circuit looks correct in terms of functionality. However, the following module uses a large amount of logic elements. It uses 24 logic elements and I'm not sure why since it should be using 8 + a couple of combinational gates for the case block.

I suspect the adder but I'm not 100% sure. If my suspicion is correct however, is it possible to use multipliers as a simple adder?

```
module alu #(parameter N = 8)
(
    output logic [N-1:0] alu_res,
    input [N-1:0] a,
    input [N-1:0] b,
    input [1:0] op,
    input clk
);       

wire [7:0] dataa, datab;
wire [15:0] result;

// instantiate embedded 8-bit signed multiplier
mult mult8bit (.*);

// assign multiplier operands
assign dataa = a;
assign datab = b;

always_comb
    unique case (op)
        // LW
        2'b00:  alu_res = 8'b0;
        // ADD
        2'b01:  alu_res = a + b;
        // MUL
        2'b10:  alu_res = result[2*N-2:N-1]; // a is a fraction
        // MOV
        2'b11:  alu_res = a;
    endcase

endmodule
```

Comment: This is a migrated question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304059/how-do-i-make-use-of-multipliers-to-generate-a-simple-adder

Comment: Your existing design is using 16 logic elements to implement the 8-bit 4:1 mux represented by the `case` statement, and 8 logic elements (in conjunction with dedicated carry hardware) to implement `a + b`. It really doesn't get much better than that.

Comment: I'll copy my comment from StackOverflow: "`unique` for synthesis means `parallel_case` and `full_case`. Try it with `priority` (only `full_case`) instead. Also try it without a keyword in front of the case statement."

Comment: From my experience, `parallel_case` tends require more logic gates but provides a faster data path.

Comment: @Greg Thanks Greg. I'll give it a try, though the textbooks I've read recommend avoiding them for some reason. I used unique because it theoretically should result in less hardware.

Comment: @Greg I've tried both priority and without a keyword. They both produce pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks. I guess I need to figure out how to simplify the alu somehow.

Comment: Style point: if you used `localparam [1:0] LW=2'b00, ADD=2'b01, MUL=2'b10...;` you'd find the output mux code self documenting (or an SV enum)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Altera "Technology Map Viewer" if you want to see exactly how/where those 24 elements are being inferred.

I'm not certain what technology you targeted. For a StratixV it uses 16 regs and 1 DSP slice  and if you need it you'll get the next register stage for free from the mux output.

RTL Viewer

[image: RTL view]

Technology/resource view
[image]

You can see the logic elements are used one per bit for the output mux and one per bit for the adder, with the DSP cell highlighted.

You might be able to pack the whole thing into a single SV DSP cell using the various mode bits (pre adders for a/b, set mult stage to x1) to avoid the output mux, but the whole thing is moot on that kind of device!